# creation of local git repository fails

Tags: linux, git, github, gitlab

I am tyring to create a local git repository with this command on ubuntu 14.10, but it fails with error "you don't have correct access rights". Any idea what could be the problem?, is it a firewall issus?

```
$git clone -o khronos git@gitlab.khronos.org:vulkan/LoaderAndTools.git .
Cloning into '.'...
ssh: connect to host gitlab.khronos.org port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using ssh directly?

Comment: Did you add your ssh key to your gitlab account ?

Comment: @marcolz Yes I generated and added my SSH key at https://gitlab.khronos.org/profile/keys .  Below is my config                                                       Host gitlab.khronos.org    
    User sami
    Hostname gitlab.khronos.org
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    Port 22
    IdentityFile /home/sami.md/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams how to try using ssh directly?

Answer (score 1):

The *Connection timed out* message indicates that your machine cannot connect to port 22.

As I can reach gitlab.khronos.org port 22 fine, my conclusion would be that it is a firewall in your local network that is the problem.